How can I avoid duplicating key in value, and duplicating type and const definitions, without using manual type assertions?
Consider following TypeScript code (codepen link):
type Name = 'foo' | 'bar'

type ProviderFuncFromString = (data: string) => { name: Name; data: string }

type ProviderFuncFromNumber = (numb: number) => { name: Name; data: string }

function providerFuncFromStringFactory(name: Name): ProviderFuncFromString {
  return (data) => ({ name, data })
}

function providerFuncFromNumberFactory(name: Name): ProviderFuncFromNumber {
  return (numb) => ({ name, data: numb.toString() })
}

type ProviderMap = {
  foo: ProviderFuncFromString
  bar: ProviderFuncFromNumber
}

const providerMap: ProviderMap = {
  foo: providerFuncFromStringFactory('foo'),
  bar: providerFuncFromNumberFactory('bar'),
}

There are two duplications here:

Both ProviderMap and providerMap say that the provider func for foo is "from string", and that provider func for bar is "from number".
In providerMap the keys foo and bar are duplicated both in the key and value.

How can I remove both of these duplications?
I don't want to use any manual type assertions like as keyword as I want to maintain type-safety provided by TypeScript.
I know that for simple string union types I can deduplicate type and const like this:
export const NameVal = ['foo', 'bar']

export type NameType = (typeof NameVal)[number]

Here foo and bar are defined only once, providing us both with type and runtime const.
However, I don't know how to apply this "trick" to more advanced types.
I tried e.g.:
type providerMapType = (typeof providerMap)[keyof typeof providerMap]

but then the type becomes
type providerMapType = ProviderFuncFromString | ProviderFuncFromNumber

and not the desired
type providerMapType = {
  foo: ProviderFuncFromString
  bar: ProviderFuncFromNumber
}

As for the duplication within providerMap of foo and bar, I was trying something like this:

function getFromStringFactory(name: Name): [Name, ProviderFuncFromString] {
  return [name, providerFuncFromStringFactory(name)]
}

function getFromNumberFactory(name: Name): [Name, ProviderFuncFromNumber] {
  return [name, providerFuncFromNumberFactory(name)]
}

const providerMap2 = Object.fromEntries([
  getFromStringFactory('foo'),
  getFromNumberFactory('bar'),
])

but here providerMap2 evaluates to const providerMap2: any.

if i understand the gist correctly, you want to have a return type of a function be inferred and propagate into further code, correct? if that's the case i'd look into some thing like Zod library (https://github.com/colinhacks/zod). Define a schema; use it to parse the return value return mySchema.parse(val); this way the TS lsp will be able to infer the return type because it'll let TS know that the return value is of the type defined by schema or throw an error. another benefit is - schemas are in runtime, so you'll catch runtime errors too, which makes TS almost type safe

@liminor thank you for the recommendation, I will look into zod. My use case is: I have a string identifying what "action on backend" I want to execute, and I want to have a strongly typed map that tells me "for action foo, this is the function you must invoke to obtain json body payload for backend call". I want to define this relationship just once in the source. If one day I add qux to valid actions list, I want for the TS compiler to guide me to update all the relevant code. I don't want duplication or manual type assertions to avoid introducing mistakes and rework.

ah, i see. it's a bit different from what i initially thought though Zod will allow for the return types to propagate through the api calls. i think a min reproducible repo/jsfiddle/etc could help so that we could play around with it. i like the concept of determining the actions via a map. could be more succinct than having a switch statement or an ungodly amount of if statements

@liminor thx for the suggestion. I added codepen link to the top of my post.

would flipping the script work for you: const providerMap = {   foo: providerFuncFromStringFactory('foo'),   bar: providerFuncFromNumberFactory('bar'), }; type ProviderMap = typeof providerMap. they way i see it, you're writing a schema without a validation library :) so why not define a map first and then infer the type of the map after?

https://codepen.io/kolchurinvv/pen/OJeVbqR it kinda works. the major issue with that implementation is that the more kinds of actions you have the larger the ternary operator for the ActionToFunctionMap type will grow. the upshot is providerMap can only have property names of the Name type and the argument to the providerFuncFrom....() can only be that property name. also, the actions are typed based on the ActionToFunctionMap

thought i suppose it didn't help with writing less code objective :)

@jcalz your solution is great. I will upvote your answer. Indeed you use as but as you say, it doesn't actually reduce typing protection, if I understand this correctly. However, there is still one problem. With your solution I can do this: providerMap.foo('bar'). I wanted to ensure that I have providerMap.foo which is equivalent to providerMap.foo('foo'). I want to ensure this without having to write foo twice in the definitions, like foo: providerFuncFromStringFactory('foo') or similar.

@liminor your solution is also great, and I would also upvote your answer. While strictly speaking you duplicate usage of names in your source, like here: bar: providerFuncFromNumberFactory('bar'),, I noticed it will fail compilation if I try to replace bar with buz (which you explained). This is what I actually care the most about - I am OK with duplicating bar, as long as the compiler tells me I made a mistake.  Does the compiler know I need to use exactly bar because of the extends operator? Let me know if you want to write an answer so I can upvote or should I do it.

@jcalz sorry, let me clarify my intent. I want a map that says: "for key foo, map to a function that returns an object that has the key name affixed to foo". If I do providerMap.foo('bar') then I have returned a function that affixes name to bar, but that function was keyed with foo in the map - this is a bug! The additional thing I want is that this map tells me exactly the function signature for each key. So it says: key foo maps to function that accepts string. bar to a function that accepts number, etc. The map key and the returned object name key value must match.

@jcalz to add: notice that in the TS playground you shared the providerMap maps to factories like foo: providerFuncFromStringFactory but in my initial code snippet from my question I want to map to the partially applied factories, like foo: providerFuncFromStringFactory('foo').

@jcalz apologies, you are absolutely right. And your solution meets all of my requirements, thank you! Somehow I failed to notice you invoke mappy( in this line: const providerMap = mappy({. Because of that I thought that if I  do console.log(providerMap.foo('bar')) then I will get ProviderFuncFromString with Name bound to bar but in fact I am getting {"name": "foo", "data": "bar"}, which is the desired behavior. Thanks again for your answer and patience!

Okay, thanks, I thought I was going crazy. So, backing up... it's only the implementation of mappy that's not compiler-verified as safe (because of the as inside it) but users of mappy don't have that problem. And mappy's impl takes care of the deduplication, since it uses the key of the input object as both a key and an argument.  Anyway I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

Since you’ve got your answer, which I like better than mine, I won’t bother writing it. The extends keyword means basically “x is a part of y”. In case of literal values like “foo” the only value x can be is “foo”

In order to stop duplicating keys entirely you'd need to do something like
const providerMap = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries({
    foo: providerFuncFromStringFactory,
    bar: providerFuncFromNumberFactory
}).map(([k, f]) => [k, f(k)]));

using Object.entries() to take an object of factories and produce an array of its property entries, then mapping these entries so that the factories are called with their key as an argument, and then using Object.fromEntries() to re-assemble that into an object.
And that works fine in JavaScript, but TypeScript doesn't follow that logic. Object.entries(), Object.fromEntries(), and generic map() aren't strongly typed enough in TypeScript for that to work. There are various questions and answers on Stack Overflow about these issues, such as Infer shape of result of Object.fromEntries() in TypeScript and Trying to get fromEntries type right and Mapping tuple-typed value to different tuple-typed value without casts.
Currently you're going to have to use type assertions somewhere. The best you can do, then, is to confine them to the inside of some function you're only going to write once, so that callers of the function can use it without worrying.
Like this, possibly:
function mapCallWithKeyAsArgument<T extends object>(
    funcs: { [K in keyof T]: (name: K) => T[K] }
) {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(funcs as { [k: string]: Function })
            .map(([k, f]) => [k, f(k)])
    ) as T
}

Here mapCallWithKeyAsArgument() takes an object of functions where each function accepts an argument of the type of the key, and produces the value we want in our output property.  The output is of the generic type T, and the input funcs is of the mapped type { [K in keyof T]: (name: K) => T[K] }. When you call it, TypeScript will infer T from the type of funcs, in a process called "inference from mapped types" (that is only documented in v1 of the TS handbook for some reason).
Inside mapCallWithKeyAsArgument(), I use type assertions twice: one which allows TypeScript to believe that every member of funcs is a function type, and one which asks TypeScript to accept that the output type is the desired T output.  Again, this isn't verified as safe by the compiler; instead we have to do it ourselves.
But now, callers of the function get the desired behavior:
const providerMap = mapCallWithKeyAsArgument({
    foo: providerFuncFromStringFactory,
    bar: providerFuncFromNumberFactory,
});
type ProviderMap = typeof providerMap;
/* type ProviderMap = {
    foo: ProviderFuncFromString;
    bar: ProviderFuncFromNumber;
} */

Here providerMap has a foo property of type ProviderFuncFromString and a bar property of type ProviderFuncFromNumber as desired!

And note that we can use the typeof type operator to derive the ProviderMap type from the providerMap value, so we don't have to duplicate foo and bar there either.
Playground link to code
